# Building SSRS Reports without Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm a software engineer who typically builds SSRS reports using Visual Studio. However, a business analyst would also like to create SSRS reports too. This user does not currently have access to Visual Studio.

Is it possible to create SSRS reports without Visual Studio?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: This might help: http://marcustalcott.com/2014/11/21/developing-ssrs-reports-without-buying-visual-studio/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - there's report builder.

If you have the SSRS Report Server set up, you can access it from there.

[image]

It's similar to SSRS in Visual Studio.

[image]

Download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29072

More Infor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213578.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much! I downloaded it and I think this will work out great. It didn't show up in IE 11 when browsing the SSRS folder. I see the other options though. But hey, the BA can just launch it like any other application. Thanks!